# Build Zip task with gradle including selected dependencies

Tags: gradle, build, dependencies

I want to create zip/war/jar artifact in gradle that includes few classes and only required dependencies

I have simple zip task as below that works:

```
 task myZip(type: Zip) {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    include 'com/mypackage/*'   
    archiveName 'myzip.zip'
    }
```

Now I want to include few of compile dependencies 
Sample build.gradle skeleton:

```
 apply plugin : 'java'
    apply plugin : 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    repositories{
    }
    configurations
    {
    }
    dependencies
    {
    compile <dependency1>
    compile <dependency2>
    compile <dependency3>
    ...

    compile <dependency20>
    myzipjar <dependency3>
    myzipjar <dependency6>
    myzipjar <dependency13>
    }
```

And to my zip task:

```
task myZip(type: Zip) {
      from sourceSets.main.output
     include 'com/mypackage/*'
    **into 'lib'
    from configurations.myzipjar**   
     archiveName 'myzip.zip'

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on required selection criteria.

You can either treat [`Configuration`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html) as a regular [`FileCollection`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html) from which you can query `File` instances:

```
configurations.compile.findAll
{
    it.name.startsWith == "required-prefix" // it is an instance of File
}
```

...or you can use its [`getResolvedConfiguration()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#getResolvedConfiguration--) method to filter resolution result by originating [`Dependency`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Dependency.html) instances:

```
configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.getFiles
{
    it.group == "target-group" // it is an instance of Dependency
}
```

Or maybe you should consider using a separate configuration that will be included into both `compile` configuration and yout zip task:

```
configurations
{
    zippableCompile
    compile.extendsFrom zippableCompile
}

dependencies
{
    zippableCompile <...>
}
```

P. S. The `compile` configuration is deprecated since Gradle 3.4, use `implementation` instead.